# Rails and MongoDB: working without ORM pros and cons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongomapper

I've just started using mongoDB with rails 3.1.

I've looked at mongoid and mongomappers ORMs: some things seems to be not very straitforward 
with ORMs, but I'm newbie to this, just wanted to know the opinion of the experienced users.

When is it a good idea to work with ORM like Mongoid and MongoMapper and where these ORMs do fail?

Actually in my application I use only REST interface when interacting with client (no ERB template views, just json objects), and I'm not sure if I need the interlayer (ORM) between mongodb (server data model) and my client data model, because I plan to have them pretty much the same.

Thanks!